# Drawer icon color

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

So I found a lot of posts with similar question and I managed to change drawer icon color by adding in toolbar styles this line `<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>` but for it to work I need to add this line to toolbar xml `android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"` but my style changes in the code and that toolbar would pick primary color after I changed theme I cannot use `android:theme` in the toolbars xml so I wonder if it's possible to set toolbar theme in styles?

I tried this but still no results

**Theme which I setting programatically**

```
<style name="mytheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>
</style>
```

**Toolbar style which has to apply to toolbar when I'm changing theme to mytheme**

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="mytheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Toolbars xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_week_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Comment: Can you share your xml code here

Comment: Toolbars xml code?

Comment: Navigation drawer code.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing with styles I figure out how to do that so instead of adding this line `<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>` to toolbar style I added it to mytheme style and it worked